# Sprite going off the borders of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I added the following in `didMoveToView` :

```
    var ground = SKNode()
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    self.addChild(ground)
```

and in the `touchesBegan`, I added the following :

```
    mainChar.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) 
    mainChar.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(85, 0))
```

Where mainChar is a SKSpriteNode that was defined earlier. I tested the above code by changing the direction of the applyImpulse in the y direction and saw that the mainChar does not go beyond the top of the screen.  However when I leave it as 85 or change it to -85, it disappears from both the right and left hand side of the screen.

What can I do differently to make sure that the mainChar stays within the bonding box of the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you given the scene a physicsBody?

Comment: errr...don't think so. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi.. I hadn't noticed earlier that you had set up the required physicsBody on the ground node, which seems right. I think the position you are setting is wrong. To make sure, call `self.view.showsPhysics = true` in the didMoveToView method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Unfortunately still doesn't work. In addition, there is now a blue circle around the main sprite for some reason.

Comment: By setting self.view.showsPhysics = true the physicsBodies are actually drawn on the scene. This helps is checking whether the physicsBodies are correctly set or not.

Comment: I see! I think it is correctly placed on the screen. It is just that the boundaries of the screen still don't seem to be respected for some reason!

Comment: @ZeMoon  , a very polite reminder of above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are your scene isn't the same size as your frame and you are using `.AspectFill`.

If you turn on physics debugging you will notice you have a green line on either top and bottom or left and right.

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

If you do this...

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
```

Everything will likely magically work but you will notice some black bars

If you print in your didMoveToView (if .AspectFill)

```
println("\(self.frame)")
println("\(view.frame)")
```

You will likely see that you are trying to fit a really big scene into a small view. Your scene gets scaled down into your view, but the size remains the same. This causes some things to get cut off (even your ground node) You will have to do some math to figure out what is getting cut off on the top and bottom. After that you will need to create a frame based on that and offset your node.

Sorry I couldn't do the math for you, but thought if I at least get you pointed in the right direction and you know why then you might figure out the rest.

Comment: Dude you are an absolute genius! That is exactly what the problem was. Sorry for the late reply as I was away. The dimensions of the self.frame and view.frame are as follows (respectively) : `(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 768.0) ` and ` (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0 )`. 


I modified the code: 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=r88ggh&s=8#.VaQm_kKBBUE

I played with the numbers and 2.0 and 1.7  work for iPhone 6. However for others, the borders seem to be in other places (such as the middle of the screen etc). Could you kindly point me in the right direction so that it can happen programatically? Many thanks!

Comment: @user3369038 Are you designing for iPad?

Comment: Basically I am new to game dev so just learning things by trying. Ideally I'd like to create a universal game that works on all devices. Is that possible? Or do I have to limit my dev to only a particular device? I realised it is not only the screen resolution but also things like the amount of dx and dy (of an impulse) that would be different, depending on the device that the game is running on. 

Would be grateful for any advice from someone as experienced as you. Thanks!!

Comment: Incase if it is not possible to build a universal app, could I maybe detect which device the game is running on? And then depending on that, I have loads of if statements that apply different dimensions for view.frame and the values of the impulses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting dynamic as false prevents the node from being affected by collisions.

Change your code as follows:

```
var ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = true //This should be set to true
ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
ground.physicsBody?.friction = 1
self.addChild(ground)
```

You will also have to set the categories for each physicsBody.

Comment: So I changed it the code to this:
        var ground = SKNode()
        ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        ground.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:self.frame)
and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Anything else I could try?